# CoffeeScript class inheritance

Tags: prototypal-inheritance, coffeescript

I'm trying to figure out how inheritance works in coffeescript. Here's a simplified example of my code:

```
class Parent

  constructor: (attrs) ->
    for own name,value of attrs
      this[name] = value

Parent.from_json_array = (json, callback) ->
  for item in JSON.parse(json)
    obj = new ChildA item  # [1]
    callback obj

class ChildA extends Parent

class ChildB extends Parent

ChildA.from_json_array("[{foo: 1}, {foo: 2}]") (obj) ->
  console.log obj.foo
```

What do I need to put on the line marked `[1]` to use the correct child class here? This works, but only creates objects with a prototype of `ChildA`. I've tried something like:

```
Parent.from_json_array = (json, callback) ->
  klass = this.prototype
  for item in JSON.parse(json)
    obj = klass.constructor item  # [1]
    callback obj
```

... but this leaves `obj` as undefined in my callback function (TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined".

Whats the magic incantation in CoffeeScript to be able to create a new object of a class, where the class is variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out:

```
Parent.from_json_array = (json, callback) ->
  klass = this
  for item in JSON.parse(json)
    obj = new klass item
    callback obj
```

Turns out you can just `new` a class stored in a variable. I thought I had tried this before, but was getting a syntax error.